# "the label [5] is not in the [index]" while duplicating rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to reformat a CSV to turn each month column into a separate row per record (essentially rotating it), i.e.,:

[image]

Into:

[image]

To do this, I thought the best way would be to:

- loop through each row, loop through for each month column (`Jan-17`, `Feb-17`, etc...), then duplicate the row.
- Then insert the month and totals into `Date` and `Totals` columns.
- Then remove that record that was duplicated and start where the index left off (I.e., after 5 record loops for each date, the index to start on would be 5).
- Then when all rows are duplicated, remove, the month columns (`Jan-17`, `Feb-17`, etc...)

It does it for the first data row (i.e., `brand1`), but after the first outer loop completes, it breaks with:

> the label [5] is not in the [index]

```
df['date'] = ''
df['totals'] = 0
months = ['Jan-17', 'Feb-17', 'Mar-17', 'Apr-17', 'May-17']

dropRowIndex = 0
nextDuplicateRowStartIndex = 0
totalRows = df.shape[0]

for i in range(0, totalRows):
    print('--------------')
    print(df)
    for col in df:
        if col in months:
            # Insert a row above 0th index with 0th row's values
            # Duplicate the row at this index for each month
            # Then move on to the next "row", which would be the latest index count
            df.loc[nextDuplicateRowStartIndex-1] = df.loc[nextDuplicateRowStartIndex].values
            df.loc[nextDuplicateRowStartIndex-1, 'date'] = col
            df.loc[nextDuplicateRowStartIndex-1, 'totals'] = df.loc[nextDuplicateRowStartIndex-1][col]

            df.index = df.index + 1
            df = df.sort_index()
            dropRowIndex += 1

    # Drop duplicated row by index
    df.drop(dropRowIndex, inplace=True)
    nextDuplicateRowStartIndex = dropRowIndex

# Remove months columns
for col in df:
    if col in months:
        df = df.drop(col, 1)
```

Terminal output:

```
-------------- INITIAL DATA FRAME:
    brand  Jan-17  Feb-17  Mar-17  Apr-17  May-17 date  totals
0  brand1     222     333     444     555     666            0
1  brand2    7777    8888    9999    1010    1111            0
2  brand3   12121   13131   14141   15151   16161            0
-------------- DATA FRAME AFTER FIRST OUTER LOOP (ROW) ITERATION:
    brand  Jan-17  Feb-17  Mar-17  Apr-17  May-17    date  totals
0  brand1     222     333     444     555     666  May-17     666
1  brand1     222     333     444     555     666  Apr-17     555
2  brand1     222     333     444     555     666  Mar-17     444
3  brand1     222     333     444     555     666  Feb-17     333
4  brand1     222     333     444     555     666  Jan-17     222
6  brand2    7777    8888    9999    1010    1111               0
7  brand3   12121   13131   14141   15151   16161               0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danielturcotte/Sites/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1506, in _has_valid_type
    error()
  File "/Users/danielturcotte/Sites/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1501, in error
    axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: 'the label [5] is not in the [index]'
```

ERROR

> KeyError: 'the label [5] is not in the [index]'

---

One thought I had was because I'm using `.loc[index]`, where index is an integer, perhaps `.loc` [doesn't work with integers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html), but `.iloc[]` does. If I do

```
df.iloc[nextDuplicateRowStartIndex-1] = df.iloc[nextDuplicateRowStartIndex].values
```

I get ERROR:

> ValueError: labels [10] not contained in axis

And the terminal output produces `NaN`s:

```
    brand  Jan-17  Feb-17  Mar-17  Apr-17  May-17    date  totals
0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  May-17     NaN
1     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  Apr-17     NaN
2     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  Mar-17     NaN
3     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  Feb-17     NaN
4     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  Jan-17     NaN
6  brand2  7777.0  8888.0  9999.0  1010.0  1111.0             0.0
7     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  Apr-17     NaN
```

Though I'm not convinced this is the issue as both `print(df.iloc[0])` and `print(df.loc[0])` yield the same results (even though I'm accessing `loc[0]` with an integer).

---

Doing `melt`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) for this. It allows you to select a number of ID columns and value columns. In your case, the value columns are everything apart from 'brand', so we can ignore that parameter. As such, you can do everything in one line:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'brand': ['brand1', 'brand2', 'brand3'],
    'Jan-17': [22, 232, 324],
    'Feb-17': [333, 424, 999]
    # ...
})

rearranged = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['brand'], var_name='Date',
                     value_name='Total')

print(rearranged)
```

This prints:

```
    brand    Date  Total
0  brand1  Feb-17    333
1  brand2  Feb-17    424
2  brand3  Feb-17    999
3  brand1  Jan-17     22
4  brand2  Jan-17    232
5  brand3  Jan-17    324
```

Comment: No worries pal! It's quite powerful, so you should always try to check if there's an automatic method of doing something.

Comment: Yeah I wanted a more functional method of doing it but couldn't find one. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Please see above terminal output (latest edit on bottom): it repeats `brand1, brand2, brand3` for the `date` and `totals` column as well. Why is this?

Comment: Because presumably you still added the `date` and `totals` column at the start - the `df['date'] = ''` and `df['totals'] = 0` lines in your question. You don't need them any more.

Answer (score 1):

By using asongtoruin's data and `stack`

```
df.set_index('brand').stack().reset_index(name='Total').rename(columns={'level_1':'Date'})
Out[1043]: 
    brand    Date  Total
0  brand1  Feb-17    333
1  brand1  Jan-17     22
2  brand2  Feb-17    424
3  brand2  Jan-17    232
4  brand3  Feb-17    999
5  brand3  Jan-17    324
```

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why this was downvoted either. Seems like `stack` is a good alternative. Wen, any thoughts why I'd use `stack` over `melt`?

Comment: @Growler If you notice the brand , stack do not change the order of your original row brand1 ,brand2,brand3, sometime , it is hard to sort back to the original one

Comment: @Growler let us say, your original order is brand2 brand1 brand3, when you do melt , it will hard to convert it back, unless you do one more steps by `sort` +`key`

Comment: I'm also not sure why this was downvoted, it's a good answer. I find `melt` more readable but in this situation that's entirely personal preference.

Comment: @asongtoruin that is ok thank you:-), btw `melt` is more general for those cases.